# Passed variable from php to ajax cant be used in SQL SELECT statements only in INSERT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

as the title says. The variable I stored from php to ajax to another php cant be use in "SELECT" statements in SQL only on "INSERT". I tried using the variable "$_POST["tweet"]" in "INSERT" statement in the SQL and it works. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BIVN.png) but in select statement it doesnt work. I cant even use echo in that variable that came from ajax.

> chatproftouser.php

```
<?php

include 'header.php';
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['UID'])){
    $userid = $_GET['UID'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE userid LIKE             '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
{
    while ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $userid = $a['userid'];
        $username = $a['username'];
        $useremail = $a['useremail'];  
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <div id=sendername>
            <p><?php echo $username ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $useremail ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="container box">
        <form name="sendmessage" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="usermessage" id="usermessage" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="right">
            <input type="button" name="sendusermessagebutton" id="sendusermessagebutton"  value="Send" class="btn btn-info" />
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id=chatprof>
            <!-- HERE IS THE CHATLOG -->
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var tweet_txt = "<?php echo $useremail?>";
            $.ajax
            ({
                url:"chatprof.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{tweet:tweet_txt},
                dataType:"text",
            });        
        });
        </script>
        <script>    
            $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval( function(){ $('#chatprof').load('chatprof.php'); }, 2000 );
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/insertusermessage.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php 
    }
    }else{

    echo "Theres is no ID like that";
    header("Location:chatprofmessenger.php");
    }
}

?>
```

And here is my another php for select statement.

> Chatprof.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST["tweet"]))
{       
    $prfemail = $_SESSION['prfemail'];
    $tweet = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tweet"]);
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM chatlogs WHERE     useremail='".$tweet."' AND prfemail='$prfemail'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
    while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $useremail = $a['useremail'];
            $message = $a['message'];
            echo $useremail;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be related to useremail='".$tweet."'. Just curious as to why a tweet would equal a user email?

Comment: You're doing `useremail='".$tweet."'` but then doing `prfemail='$prfemail'`.  That looks inconsistent syntax wise.

Comment: do you get any value for `$_POST['tweet']` at all?

Comment: I suppose you'll find your 'tweet' in `file_get_contents("php://input");` (then json_decode it)

Comment: @jeff Yes . only if I use the INSERT . but when I use SELECT in query . nothing happens.

Comment: where is the version with the insert that is working?